# ElementaryOS on Pentium D

Tags: vaio

I recently got my hands on a 3.2 Ghz Pentium D with 4 Gigs of Ram.(3.25 allocated in windows for some reason) Has anyone had any success running Elementary OS loki on and older computer. I find my self always going back to Lubuntu and not really enjoying it. I am going to install it this weekend because I will have to make a bootable DVD because for some reason its super hard to boot from a USB on old Sony Vaios. I much rather run ElementaryOS that Lubuntu and I believe im board with LinuxMint. Any Opinions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine! The [minimum system specs](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#recommended-system-specifications) are:

- Intel i3 or comparable dual-core 64-bit processor
- 1 GB of system memory (RAM)
- 15 GB of disk space
- Internet access

The Pentium D is 64-bit, which is the only hard processor limitation. 4GB of RAM is of course way over the minimum specs. You can always boot into the live DVD to be sure, but you should be fine.

YouTube has a [video of someone installing elementary OS Loki on a Sony Vaio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9KMrTfFwYxY), and everything seemed to go pretty smoothly.